# Spinning wheel or 360 degree rotation wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for some jquery plugin or any code examples for multiple spinning wheels or 360 degree rotation wheels.  Attached is the demo image for which, I am looking for the solution, where all the wheel can be rotate and This is basically develop birthdate selection somewhat like desktop and mobile application...But I need for my web application. I am using PHP & Apache web server.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any idea or sameple code or similer solution to moving forward

-Himanshu

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any ready made solutions, but I can point you in two directions you can go:

- You can make an image for each of the 3 different wheels with the correct sizes and next use css3 transformations to rotate the specific wheels with javascript ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#rotate )
- The other option is to look into the html5 canvas tag and draw the wheels onto it by hand. Here is a tutorial which covers making a roulette game on a canvas tag, which is quite different from your requirements, but does describe the necessary techniques. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for yor prompt responce.  

I have lreadt check second link, but it's have some cross browsers issue , specially for IE, it's now working in IE.... Let me try analyse the first link

Comment: Both will *not* work in pre IE9, if you want to make it IE8- compatible you will have to either rotate the images server side or go into ms specific trickery. If you want to go with the 'clean' approach you can see the compability tables here http://caniuse.com/#search=transformat (first approach) and http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas (second approach). Lastly if you want to go with the ms trickery http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples handles this nicely for you it seems, but I haven't used that plugin.

Comment: humm. Let me try once...I want to ptovide support for IE7 & Higher, Crome & FF... so looking for browser friendly solution, atleast which i have mesnioned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes HTML5 canvas rotate() is the way to go with this. My site http://www.dougtesting.net has a winning wheel that uses canvas rotation, but only for one wheel image. The code is fully commented so you may find it a useful starting point.

For your project you would probably need multiple images that are rendered to the canvas and rotated to the desired angles. Also you will probably need to look in to a mouseDown, mouseMove, and mouseUp code to allow the user to drag the wheels to the desired locations, with the code being able to tell you the values pointed at (something the code in my winning wheel can also do).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you ask. In terms of browser compatibility, I recommend you to take a look at the excellent [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) JavaScript library. It allows you to draw and rotate a wheel using vector graphics. Best of all, this library is IE6+ compatible and works in most if not all modern webbrowsers, including tablets and mobile phones.

To ease the creation of the necessary vector graphics, you can draw the wheel in a vector image editor of your choice (e.g. Illustrator, Inkscape, etc..) and save the vector image as SVG file. A very convenient online companion tool called [ReadySetRaphael](http://www.readysetraphael.com/) takes an SVG file as input and produces the necessary JavaScript to draw the graphics automatically.

If you have the path of the vector graphic as an object in JavaScript, it is easy to rotate it with the `Element.rotate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure if a plugin exists for this purpose;In my current project we have made a context menu using the canvas api which is not that different from your requirement, if not a bit more complex. Therefore, I highly recommend using the HTML5 Canvas api to do this, if you are not restricted from it. You can use a few ideas from the interactive flower tutorial.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-flower/

This should help too if you're interested in bringing jQuery into play.
http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/